# Push to same github repository spring and react project

Tags: git, github

I want to upload react and spring projects in the same repository. I get this error when trying to push the other after pushing one. When I use --force, the other project's code is deleted. How can I store both together in the repository?

```
bar1s@DESKTOP-C8L726O MINGW64 ~/Desktop/spring/auction-project (master)
$ git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/cevikbaris/Auction-Website.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/cevikbaris/Auction-Website.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Git has a simple rule: one branch name holds one hash ID. You can't make one branch name hold two hash IDs. Use two different branch names if you want to hold two different hash IDs.

Comment: If you have two projects, you should probably use two different repos, or at least create different subdirectories for each project in the same repo. But I would avoid having the two projects on two separate branches of the same repo, that's just gong to cause confusion in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have the two projects in the same repository either on two different [branches](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository) on the repository, or you store both projects in the same directory.

The issue you get here is the following:
When you push one of your projects, changes are made to the online repository that you then, in turn, do not have in your local ones. Hence you cannot push, as git does not know what to do with the different code in this situation.

**How to fix this**
Solution 1:
Store both projects in the same directories.
To fix your problem quickly, simply run

```
git pull
```

before trying to *git push* your project.
This will pull the changes to your local repository, and likely create a mess if you have any directories with equal names.
But you will be able to push.

Solution 2:
Create different branches for both projects.
Do this with the following commands:

```
git branch <branch name> //create a new branch
git branch               //view your branches
git switch <branch name> //switch to the specified branch
```

You can then push your projects on individual branches while still working in the same repository.

Reference:

- [Github: Manage branches](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository)

Comment: There is also solution 3: create the two projects as two different subdirectories of the same repo, which will avoid the mess you're describing in solution 1.